# How to install Node.js when I get Rolling back action every time?

Tags: node.js, windows, failed-installation

I wanted to learn Node.js so I tried to install it. Lik every time I am installing something new, I get thousands of error messages in my face. I already deletet one key in the register that should stop the download (Didnt work). The I tried to download it without the Performance Counter activated. I really dont know what to do else.
I am currently using a Windows 10 as OS and version 8 and 10 of Node.js (both didnt work).
In addition here is the code of the Log file while installation:

```
'https://pastebin.com/LQE6k2MX'
```

I really hope to get any advise on how to fix this installation problem.
On my Linux OS I was able to install and use it properly.

Sincerely,

Me

Answer (score 7):

If you have downloaded the latest LTS version of the node and the installation ends up prematurely, please try install again with the EWT disabled.

1. Run the installation
2. On **Custom Setup** step expand the *Node.js runtime* node
3. Left click on *Event tracing (ETW)* option and choose the **Feature will be installed when required**
4. Finish the installation

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks, HeLlOwOrLd. 
I had the same problem and your suggestion solved the issue.